# Hoa can I get the session id and pass it to an encryption function?

Tags: authentication, jmeter, password-encryption

Here is the specific code that uses the session key and passes it to the server for authentication

```
    a2 = encrypt.AESEncrypt(a2, "<%=(String)session.getAttribute("__GETLOGINKEY")%>", 256);
```

been stuck in doing the login page for days. appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the full code, unfortunately we're not able to help you with this very limited one line.

If you need to encrypt the request parameter using [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) algorithm and send it
I can only suggest using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) for that.

Check out [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy) which contains some code snippets for AES encryption. There is also [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article which sheds some light on Groovy scripting in JMeter.

However `session.getAttribute` looks like to be a [server-side code](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html), I think you should rather take a look at client-side, for example there should be some [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) function performing parameters encryption or something like this.

Comment: Function in login.jsp calls the server-side code.  function getControlPrefix() {var a2 = document.forms[0].a2.value;
  var a2n = "";
  for(var i=0; i < a2.length; i++){
   a2n += "*";}
  var type="<%=SystemParameters.getInstance().getParameter(SystemParameters.KEY_AUTHENTICATION_TYPE)%>";
            a2 = encrypt.AESEncrypt(a2, "<%=(String)session.getAttribute("__GETLOGINKEY")%>", 256);
  document.forms[0].a3.value = a2;
  document.forms[0].a2.value = a2n;
  document.forms[0].txtResFrac.value= screen.width;
  if (getControlPrefix.prefix){
   return getControlPrefix.prefix; }